# Calling swift completion block in Objective C class file. Error: parameter name omitted

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, objective-c-blocks

I am attempting to call the following Swift function from an Objective C class.

**swift class function**

```
@objc public func loaddevice(completionswift:@escaping (String) -> Void){
      appSyncClient?.fetch(query: GetDevicesQuery(), cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataAndFetch)  { (result, error) in
          if error != nil {
              print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
              return
          } else if let str = result?.data?.devices?.deviceId {
              completionswift(str)
          }
      }
}
```

I am calling it from the Objective C class like this:

```
[self.appClient loaddeviceWithCompletionswift:^(NSString * _Nonnull) {

}];
```

It is giving me error: **parameter name omitted**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to name your parameter.

```
[self.appClient loaddeviceWithCompletionswift:^(NSString * _Nonnull str) {

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
[self.appClient loaddeviceWithCompletionswift:^(NSString * _Nonnull deviceID) {

}];
```

Where `deviceID` will be the `NSString` passed in the completion block